# Specific POI types in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, point-of-interest

I only need to display only food cord. Is there any filter for POIs? I have done this so far, but this does not solve my question ...

```
  [
    {
      \"featureType\": "poi",
      \"elementType\": \"all\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"visibility\": \"off\"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      \"featureType\": \"poi.business\",
      \"elementType\": \"labels.icon\",
      \"stylers\": [
        {
          \"visibility\": \"on\"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: How is `apache-poi` involved here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cloud-based maps styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-based-map-styling) to control the behavior and appearance of points of interest (POIs) on the map. You can use the [POI filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/poi-behavior-customization#poi_filtering) to enable only the `Food and drink` POI to show in the map. You can achieve this by:

1. Setting the visibility of `Points of interest` > `All element type- All` >  `Stylers=Visibility - Off`
   [image]
2. Then click the `Points of interest-Business-Food & drinks`> `All` > `Visibility - On`
   [image]